# Astra Linux for small business?

Tags: linux, debian

I am starting a small business (in Western Europe) and investigating the Unix-like options available for desktop OS. The criteria are the following:

1. scalable (from 2 laptops right now to "unlimited" if the business is successful
2. secure
3. adapted to business use (stable, proven use in enterprise, adapted to PC fleet management, not an exotic distro)
4. free version upgradable to enterprise with technical support
5. User-friendly for people coming from Windows

Astra Linux (astralinux.ru) seems to tick all the boxes since it is Debian based, deployed or intended to be deployed in many businesses and large official administrations in Russia, and is by design oriented towards security.

a. do you think that would be a wise choice considering the current geopolitical situation?

b. if not, what inconvenience could we face in the future?

c. is Astra Linux totally open source and auditable, or is there a risk of hidden spyware installed for the benefit of Russian government?

Apologies in advance for any "naive" question. I am a Linux newbie.

Thanks and regards

P.S.: @nate - I saw on one of your posts that you are a Astra Linux user. Will appreciate your feedback if you see this post.

Comment: What does "adapted to business use" mean?

Comment: Hi terdon, thanks for you quick comment. By "adapted to business" I meant to disqualify all the distro which would not fit in this description. I am not sure how to precisely define it. An OS which is commonly used in the enterprise world and deployed on staff computers would fit this category I guess. Stability would be another aspect of it. A super customizable and cutting edge distro like Arch for example would disqualify. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: You're welcome, but please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "adapted to business use".

Comment: OK, the question is now updated.

Comment: Right now (March 2022) any western european organisation considering deploying software from Russia (or more specifically, the `.ru` domain) should think about this very carefully. I don't believe you can look at this from an exclusively technical perspective, but if you want to do so, think about support and ongoing maintenance.

Comment: A distribution specifically designed for the Russian military seems like the very definition of an "exotic distro", it doesn't get much more exotic than that. That said, I think you're just looking for Fedora with the possibility of later upgrading to Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

Comment: Thanks for the advice terdon (Fedora --> RHEL). As for Astra, maybe the word is not well-chosen, but my point of view is that if millions (even if Russians) use it daily at work, it is not exotic anymore. To the contrary, it makes it "enterprise-proven" over time and successive releases.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that a minor, super specific distro is used by millions. Both Ubuntu and Fedora/RedHat offer what you want and _are_ used by millions. I had never even heard of this Astra Linux before today. Also remember that Linux is inherently more secure than Windows, I really doubt you need military-grade security features for your small business.

Comment: Yes, definitely do not need military-grade security, but Astra has a "Common Edition" of its distro which is free and comes with allegedly improved security features. This, added to the fact it will be deployed in administrations and small businesses makes it quite unique I believe, but maybe I am wrong and got too excited about it. Will download and try it for some time along with another mainstream distro to compare. Thanks for your time and advice anyway. Having some feed-back from an Astra user would be great though (let's see if a specimen of this rare species shows up here...).

Comment: Astra Linux most certainly isn't a widely used distribution and you'd probably have a hard time finding anyone who can support it. Ubuntu, on the other hand, can be had for free and has widespread usage and support via the community which makes paid support less necessary. It even has an LTSC version that is supported for ten years.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Linux. First of, unless you are really looking for compliance, I don't believe anybody *must* upgrade to enterprise level Linux. You can also choose to hire one or more good techs that look after your systems.

In the "debian" family, I guess Ubuntu is the most friendly to newcomers and widely supported. Offers Long Term Support releases. You can get [paid support](https://ubuntu.com/pricing/infra) without switching to an enterprise distribution. Often software developers offer debian packages prebuild, in case you need those applications to be cutting edge, instead of waiting for the next LTS release.

Even Debian itself can be a good choice. Don't be intimidated by the website that doesn't look as fancy as the rest. The distribution is rock solid and "just works". The installer lets you choose the desktop environment you want, instead of needing to install a spin-off like Kubuntu, xubuntu etc. They are not backed by a single company, but there are plenty of [consultants](https://www.debian.org/consultants/).

In the "Red hat" family there is fedora. The release schedule is shorter and no LTS. But, you can switch to Red Hat Enterprise Linux later on and feel familiar with the tools. *There is also CentOS**.

Then there is the "SUSE" family. Similar like above, there is OpenSUSE with short term releases and SUSE Linux enterprise.

Security really depends on best practices and your needs. All of the above have a good reputation of patching vulnerabilities as they come out. With all of them you can choose to enable disk encryption, different types of user authentication management or security frameworks like selinux and apparmor.

**) As pointed out in the comments, the rolling release schedule for CentOS might not be suitable for some businesses.*

Comment: CentOS Stream is available but it's an upstream, rolling release that isn't suitable for a business. The CentOS that would have been suitable for this is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your time and the detailed answer. The insight on the unnecessary enterprise upgrade is very valuable as it widens the spectrum of possibilities. Debian seems a good choice for us then (because stability, robustness and available consultant expertise). We will install it, along with our minimum necessary programs, and will think about the security issue later: But "security" is probably a fad of ours.

Comment: Thank you Nasir, noted. I heard about the CentOS termination by RH. The server OS is another matter we’ll have to think about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NasirRiley. I did catch something around that topic, but I'm not so much into that Linux family. So I just made a small mention. I've updated the answer.

Comment: As for CentOS - what about Oracle Linux? It is also a RHEL clone, but doesn't seem to adopt the rolling-release model of CentOS Stream.